# Unable to get Android App Link to work in an Android app written in Flutter

Tags: android, android-intent, flutter

I am trying to implement Moneris hosted pay page from a flutter mobile app **but this question is relevant to any app that wants to implement Android App Links**.  In order to redirect back from the hosted pay page, I need to implement Android App Link (haven't gotten to do iOS version yet).  Based on [this](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking) article, in order for App Links to work, one needs:

1. Identify a redirect URL on the Moneris hosted pay page (or on the page where a redirect might take place, in case of a generic example);
2. Modify AndroidManifest.xml to associate redirects with activities;
3. Implement a way in Flutter to intercept App Links;
4. Place the Digital Asset Links JSON file on the web site (same domain as redirect URL) in the .well-known folder.

For #1, I have identified 2 URLs, one for approved payments (https://example.com/moneris_approved) and one for declined payments (https://example.com/moneris_declined).  URLs have to be in https for the whole thing to work.  Moneris can reply with a POST with XML, POST with parms or GET with parms.  Tried all three.

For #2, I have modified AndroidManifest.xml both by hand and with help of Android Studio. Relevant pieces look like this:

```xml
<application
    android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
    android:label="<label>"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
    <activity
        android:name=".MainActivity"
        android:launchMode="singleTop"
        android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme"
        ...              
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>

        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />    
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />    
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPattern="/moneris_approved" />
        </intent-filter>    
        <intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />   
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />    
            <data
                android:scheme="https"
                android:host="example.com"
                android:pathPattern="/moneris_declined" />
        </intent-filter>    
    </activity>
</application>
```

For #3, I am using uni_links package which takes care of channeling incoming App Links to my app.

For #4, I have created and uploaded the assetlinks.json file and placed in the right folder.  Included both debug and release SHA256 fingerprints.  The file looks like this:

```json
[
    {
        "relation": ["delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls"],
        "target": {
            "namespace": "android_app",
            "package_name": "com.example.<name>",
            "sha256_cert_fingerprints":
            ["........"]
        }
    }
]
```

Now, after doing all that, when Moneris redirects to provided URLs, I am seeing a 404 page coming from my hosting site.

To verify the setup, I have:

- Successful tested statement file with the [Statement List Generator and Tester](https://developers.google.com/digital-asset-links/tools/generator);
- Successfully tested digital asset link file with Google APIs (https://digitalassetlinks.googleapis.com/v1/statements:list?source.web.site=https://example.com&relation=delegate_permission/common.handle_all_urls)
- Successfully tested the URL intent using ADB shell (am start -W -a android.intent.action.VIEW -c android.intent.category.BROWSABLE -d "https://example.com/moneris_approved")
- Successfully checked link policies using ADB (adb shell dumpsys package d)
  [image]

At this point, I don't know how else to test it or what the problem is.  I don't think the problem is with my app but rather soemthing is not closing the loop between Moneris redirect and it coming back to my app.

## Update 1

I devised a testing approach like this:

1. Created a link-test page on my site with links mimicking redirects (i.e. same host/path as in the app's AndroidManifest.xml;
2. Created a simple Java Android App using Android Studio.  Using App Link Assistant I updated its AndroidManifest, created intents and reacted to those coming in.  Also updated the assetlinks.json file on my website.  Tested it with the link-test page running on my emulator and everything worked as expected.  App opened up ok.
3. Repeated #2 but this time with a Flutter app using the uni_links package.  Went throught he same steps of creating slightly different links on my link-test page, updating AndroidManifest and assetlinks.json file.  Tested it with the link-test page running on my emulator and everything worked as expected.  App opened up ok.
4. Run the app I am working on on the emulator and put the links I am expecting to get from Moneris on my link-test page and tsted on the emulator.  Everything worked as expected.  App opened up ok.

So now my question is: what is the difference between me clicking on a link on my page (HTTP GET) vs. Moneris redirecting to the same link using HTTP GET?  Me clicking on the link works.  Moneris redirect does not.

Comment: Have you tried testing your implementation using the App Links Assistant? In Android Studio, Ctrl + Shift + A -> App Links Assistant -> Test App Links. It might give you some relevant errors.

Answer (score 2):

I can see that you want to handle deep link right in the flutter code. That is possible but you have to use one of the libraries for that - for example [this](https://pub.dev/packages/uni_links).

If you want to do it by yourself you have to create a [platform specific Method Channels](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/platform-integration/platform-channels) for that. [This](https://stackoverflow.com/a/45364350/9248201) answer shows how to do it.

Also you can find a more detailed explanation [here](https://medium.com/flutter-community/deep-links-and-flutter-applications-how-to-handle-them-properly-8c9865af9283)

Hope it helps.

Comment: I will review the last link (to the Medium article) but as for the rest, I am using the uni_link flutter package.  And I have it tested with all tests provided by Google yet it still does not work.  Hence my question.

Answer (score 1):

#### This soution is not working for this case‍♀️

> thanks for clarification. Unfortunately, Moneris only supports http and https schemas so using com.googleusercontent.apps as schema will not work for me. And while I get that it works for you, your implementation contradicts my understanding of how Android App Links should work

### 01.The problem

Failed to lanch the app after Redirect

### 02.The analysis of the problem

=> (1) App (lanch browser)

==> (2) browser (  Moneris.com)

===> (3) browser (redirct to example.com)

=====> (4)  browser (404 page)❌

======> (5) failed because the app is not launched❌

### 03.Why Step 4 failed

- because you used **a real domain schema**
- the browser used the DNS not ask the OS to lanch the app

### 04.Solution

- Use com.googleusercontent.apps Url

### 05.Example returnUrl solution

```
String returnUrl =
    "com.googleusercontent.apps.932931520452-buv2dnhgo7jjjjv5fckqltn367psbrlb:/approved)";
String cancelUrl =
    "com.googleusercontent.apps.932931520452-buv2dnhgo7jjjjv5fckqltn367psbrlb:/declined)";
```

### 06.Example manifest

```
    <manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" package="com.example.e042_flutter_paypal_f">
        <application android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication" android:label="e042_flutter_paypal_f" android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher">
            <activity android:name=".MainActivity" android:launchMode="singleTop" android:theme="@style/LaunchTheme" android:configChanges="orientation|keyboardHidden|keyboard|screenSize|locale|layoutDirection|fontScale|screenLayout|density|uiMode" android:hardwareAccelerated="true" android:windowSoftInputMode="adjustResize">

                <meta-data android:name="io.flutter.app.android.SplashScreenUntilFirstFrame" android:value="true" />
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER"/>
                </intent-filter>
                <intent-filter>
                    <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW"/>
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
                    <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />
                    <!-- Custom Path data -->
                    <data android:path="/auth" android:scheme="com.googleusercontent.apps.932931520452-buv2dnhgo7jjjjv5fckqltn367psbrlb"/>
                </intent-filter>
            </activity>
        </application>
    </manifest>
```

---

#### ⚠ Warning ⚠ If there is a **Client Secret** stored in the App (i didn't use Moneris, but i asume there is a **Client Secret**), and the app is not inted for the internal use of the company , it's very very bad

---

### Ref.

- [Create Deep Links to App Content  |  Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links/deep-linking.html)
- [android - Intent filter using path,pathPrefix, or pathPattern - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19395938/intent-filter-using-path-pathprefix-or-pathpattern)
- [manifest data-element Android Developers](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/data-element)
- [Android deep links not following path prefix - Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34276617/android-deep-links-not-following-path-prefix/34294272)

Comment: thanks for suggesting an answer but I think you might have misunderstood the intent of what I am trying to do here.  This has nothing to do with authentication or authorization - I looked up apps.googleusercontent.com and it took me here (https://developers.google.com/identity/sign-in/web/server-side-flow).  Consequently, no Client Secret is passed on the call.

Comment: @Igor  I use this URL Sechma for paypal redirect, it's not specific for authentication or authorization , also good to know that there is no client secret stroed in the app

Comment: thanks for clarification.  Unfortunately, Moneris only supports http and https schemas so using com.googleusercontent.apps as schema will not work for me.  And while I get that it works for you, your implementation contradicts my understanding of how Android App Links should work as per this: https://developer.android.com/training/app-links.  i am puzzled.

Comment: @Igor  thanks for the [link](https://developer.android.com/training/app-links) , your are right  , I used the url to skip the verification step for local devlopment , 
 try to change android:pathPatter to  android:pathPrefix

Comment: Glad I could help...mind you, I'm back to square one.